# Chef knife bootstrap failed missing validation.pem on node

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Following the tutorial at: https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/manage-a-node/ubuntu/virtualbox/bootstrap-your-node/

I tried to run the bootstrap commmand that resolved in an error about missing `/etc/chef/validation.pem` on the node file system. The validation.pem should be there according to this post: 
[Chef clients and validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788920/chef-clients-and-validators),

Chef details on my workstation (not the node):

> Chef Development Kit Version: 1.0.3
>   chef-client version: 12.16.42
>   delivery version: master (83358fb62c0f711c70ad5a81030a6cae4017f103)
>   berks version: 5.2.0
>   kitchen version: 1.13.2

I'd appriciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: Which command did you run exactly ? Did you use `--sudo` in the bootstrap command ?

Comment: @Tensibai  The same command as in the tutorial, replacing the --ssh-port and --identity-file. i.e: knife bootstrap localhost --ssh-port 2200 --ssh-user vagrant --sudo --identity-file /root/learn-chef/chef-server/.vagrant/machines/node1-ubuntu/virtualbox/private_key --node-name node1-ubuntu --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'

Comment: A full log would help to pinpoint what's failing. The content of your knife.rb file also.